# ¿Porque el cuerpo de una respuesta no se puede leer más de una vez?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Este código lanza una excepción cuando intento procesar el cuerpo de la respuesta una segunda vez?

¿Cuál es la razón de este comportamiento? Porque hay que usar `request.clone()` para poder procesar una segunda vez y de otro modo la respuesta a mi petición? Porque existe esa restricción?

```
fetch('/whatever').then(function(response) {
      response.body.asJSON().catch(function() {
        // parsing as JSON failed, let's get the text
        response.body.asText().then(function(text) {
          // ...
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si miramos [la documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Response), vemos que el objeto `response` implementa la interfaz `Body`, que es la que te permite obtener el atributo `body`.

Pero `response.body` es un *Stream*, es decir, un flujo de datos. Un Stream sólo se puede procesar una vez. Por tanto debes saber de antemano si los datos están en formato JSON o no, por ejemplo mirando el `content-type` de la respuesta

De todos modos no necesitas usar el atributo `body` para obtener los datos, puedes directamente llamar al método `json()` o al método `text()`:

```js
async function getPeople() {
  const responsePromise = await fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/');
  const contentType = responsePromise.headers.get("content-type");
  const isJSON = (contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1)
  if (isJSON) {
     const obj = await responsePromise.json();
     console.log(obj);
  } else {
    const text = await responsePromise.text();
    console.log(text);
  }
}

getPeople();
```